# How to run a program when a folder is opened?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, script

I've created a program that when opened displays a message. Now I want to do this - the program must automatically get executed when a folder in my PC is opened (opened by an user).
How can I do it?
The folder can be any folder of my choice.

Comment: Any folder or a specific folder?  Opened by any means (command or any application)?

Comment: @fixer1234 I've edited my question.

Comment: @Matthew Williams I've edited my question.

Comment: You edited the part that was clear but didn't address the part that isn't.  When any/all folder is opened or when a specific folder is opened? Opened by what? (any command?  any application?)

Comment: @fixer1234 I've again edited the question. Edited the part which was unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do this natively.

However, you could possibly do it with something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

A number of possible approaches are outlined in this [article](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/85660-run-scripts-when-window-opensbecomes-active/). The best approach seems to be:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, test, 500
return

test:
  IfWinNotActive, Create Event Log 
     return

sendinput test
winwaitclose, Create Event Log 
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party software like [Folder Actions](http://folder-actions-for-windows.en.softonic.com/), (something like Folder Actions in Macs). But that's probably not what you want.
If you want to mimic the AutoPlay function for removable drives, you can [Map folder to drive letter](https://superuser.com/questions/644684/mapping-drive-letters-to-local-folders).