# "net use" does not create drives in Explorer on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, net-use

```
C:\Windows\system32>net use  
OK           X:        \\192.168.8.109\Public    Microsoft Windows Network  
OK           Y:        \\192.168.8.109\DATA      Microsoft Windows Network  
OK           Z:        \\192.168.8.109\MEDIA     Microsoft Windows Network
```

Command-line instructions like `dir x:` work as expected.

In Windows Explorer, why do these 3 mapped drives not show up? Suggestions and diagnostic questions are appreciated.

Comment: did you run the CMD as admin?

Comment: Good question: CMD was run as admin.  In the past I have had success without invoking as admin.  Perhaps something was done / configured to prevent network drives from appearing in file explorer?

Answer (score 29):

Mapped network drives created by an elevated process will not be visible to an unelevated process and vice versa. This has been the case since Windows Vista. Since Explorer doesn't run elevated (unless you fully disable UAC), it doesn't see the drives you made with your administrative command prompt.

To disable that isolation, you can modify the Registry, as instructed by [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx). Navigate to this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Create a DWORD entry named `EnableLinkedConnections` with a value of 1. Reboot the computer. Network drives mapped by the same user, even under different security contexts, will always appear to programs running as that user.

Comment: Worked on Win10 Enterprise

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: @BoarGules This still works for me on Windows 10 1909 Home. It does require a reboot after setting the Registry value, though.

Comment: Worked on Win10 Pro.  Thanks for the link to the TechNet article.

Comment: Worked! Windows 10 Enterprise, cool :).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.
When I ran the following using a CMD console with admin privileges, the drive wasnt showing up in File Explorer.

```
net use y: \\192.168.20.1\disk1_1 /p:yes
```

I then tried doing the same using a normal CMD console, and it is now showing up in File Explorer.

Comment: Makes sense. If I had to guess, running the command as admin would theoretically map the drive for the Administrator account.