# How does one list all of the junciton points (mount points) on a Windows NTFS file system?

Tags: windows, ntfs, ntfs-junction

I know how to [create these now](https://superuser.com/questions/244562/how-do-i-mount-a-network-drive-to-a-folder), but I don't know how to run something similar to `mount` in bash to list them all.