# Mounting password protected share to Windows 10 folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, mount, network-shares, lan

I need to have a network share with restricted access mounted as folder at my local Windows 10 machine.

So that the share is available immediately as it is accessed through the folder it is mounted to, without any prompt to enter the login credentials.

Is it possible?

I have found only [this](https://superuser.com/questions/244562/how-do-i-mount-a-network-drive-to-a-folder) article here at Super User which explains how to mount a share to a local Windows folder, but it provides no information about adding the login and password to the mounted path.

So far I've tried `mklink /d "c:\data\network docs" "login:password@\\server\shareddata\"` but it doesn't seem to be a working solution.

Comment: Can you try mapping to a network drive, saving the username and password when prompted, enabling the restore connection at login feature and then mklink a folder to the network drive instead of the network share? Alternately use `net use` to enable access to the share and specify a username and password then mklink to create the link. That may need to be repeated each logon though.

Comment: Of course I can do all of that. But the goal is to mount the restricted share to a folder without any additional steps.

Comment: Mklink by itself will not authenticate to a network share. That’s not what the command is for.

Comment: If you're storing the password you're losing the security. Why don't you use one of the correct methods for securing data and access g it?

Comment: Because I need this share to be mounted this way. ;)